# If/else within loop with Dust.js

Tags: dust.js

I am attempting to assign different values within a loop depending on a value within the loop.

For the following input:

```
{
  "products":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Ruby on Rails Tote",
      "has_variants":false,
      "master":{
        "id":1,
        "name":"Ruby on Rails Tote",
        "sku":"ROR-00011",
        "price":"15.99",
        "weight":"0.0",
        "height":null,
        "width":null,
        "depth":null,
        "is_master":true,
        "slug":"ruby-on-rails-tote",
        "description":"Autem ducimus ipsum temporibus doloremque voluptatem eos ea. Et esse nobis consequatur quam tempora quia assumenda. Ipsam magni quaerat ipsa ut commodi et quae. Eligendi rerum in ratione id et nemo sunt. Atque dolore voluptatem quis accusantium id.",
        "track_inventory":true,
        "cost_price":"17.0",
        "option_values":[

        ],
        "display_price":"$15.99",
        "options_text":"",
        "in_stock":true,
        "is_backorderable":true,
        "total_on_hand":50,
        "is_destroyed":false
      },
      "variants":[

      ],

      ...
```

If the `has_variants` property is `false` I want to use the property `master.id`, otherwise, iterate over the variants (there could be multiple per product), and use the `id` property of each variant.

I have attempted the following:

```
<outer>{~n}
{#products}
{@eq key=has_variants value=true}
The ID is {master.id}{~n}
{:else}
{#variants}
The ID is {id}{~n}
{/variants}
{/eq}
{/products}
</outer>
```

Which only prints out the variant ids, and omits the master ids.

How do I iterate over a list and conditional use properties based on the value of property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right. But instead of using `eq`, just use the property directly. `eq` is for loose comparisons.

```
<outer>{~n}
  {#products}
    {#has_variants}
      The ID is {master.id}{~n}
    {:else}
      {#variants}
        The ID is {id}{~n}
      {/variants}
    {/has_variants}
  {/products}
</outer>
```

Comment: If you ever really want to use `eq`, remember that all Dust helpers take only reference, string, and number arguments. So if you want to compare to true, use `{@eq key=has_variants value="true" type="boolean"}` to force the conversion of `value` and the comparator from string to bool.